# validate post json data server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use javascript nodejs as server side , each time get post from client side, I will validate the data, make sure data structure each key/value exist, so I do something like below.

I wonder is there any better idea to do this, maybe much readable,
because I put each level into one if(..) and can't change line like json/javascript object so it is long and hard to maintain .

usually people how to do this?
build a correct json object strcture, and compare with post data ?

any suggestion will be appreciate

correct data should be like:

```
request.data = {
  "user": {
    "status": "int",
    "role": {
      "role": "int"
    },
    "information": {
      "email": "text",
      "password": "text",
      "username": "text",
      "country": "text",
      ... a lot ....
    }
  },
}
```

server side validate

```
    var validateRequest = 'true';
    if (typeof request.data.user == 'undefined') {
      validateRequest = 'false';
    } else {
      if (typeof request.data.user.status == 'undefined' || typeof request.data.user.role == 'undefined' || typeof request.data.user.information == 'undefined') {
        validateRequest = 'false';
      } else {
        if (typeof request.data.user.role == 'undefined' || typeof request.data.user.information.email == 'undefined'  ... ) {
           validateRequest = 'false';
        }
      }
    } 

    if (validateRequest != 'false') {
      // validate data type

      // use data crud

    }
```

**update**

I try to set a correct json structure in server side, and compare with post, 
I found some json diff [module](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch)  but can't find how to correct usage only compare key

```
var a = {
  "information": {
    "email": "text",
    "password": "text"
  }
}

var b = {
  "information": {
    // "email": "text",
    "password": "text"
  }
}
console.log(jsondiffpatch.diff(a, b));
I only know if data not different will get undefined  
if b remove "email"   
get this in console ?? ¨ information: ¨ email: ÿ 'text', 0, 0 ¦ ¼ ¼
if b email val = textt 
get this information: ¨ email: ÿ 'text', 'textt' ¦ ¼ ¼
```

Comment: Iterate over JSON object using a loop.

Comment: If you're open to using a library, I've found [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to be a pleasure to work with for object validation.

Comment: @wolfemm seems so cool I'll try now

Answer (score 1):

I can't find way determine the result after use [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) in my question, key different or value different,
so I find another module https://github.com/mirek/node-rus-diff  it works just check $unset or $set

```
var diff = require('rus-diff').diff;

var result = diff(a, b);

if (typeof result.$unset != 'undefined') {
  console.log('different key');
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) module to observe differences in the structure of the request.

To obtain the `diff` function from the `jsondiffpatch` module:

```
var diff = require('jsondiffpatch').diff;
```

To validate the request, you can compare the request to a template. For example, a template is defined below:

```
var requestTemplate = {
  "user": {
    "status": "int",
    "role": {
      "role": "int"
    },
    "information": {
      "email": "text",
      "password": "text",
      "username": "text",
      "country": "text",
      ... a lot ....
    }
  },
}
```

To compare the request to the template, find the difference between the two:

```
var delta = diff(request.data, requestTemplate);
```

Search the delta for any property with a value of this signature:

```
'email': ['text', 0, 0]
```

This signature indicates that the property was deleted. For example, the value above indicates that the `request.data` object does not have an `email` property. The absence of this property means that the request is invalid.

You could define a function to perform the validation like so:

```
function validateRequest(template, requestData) {
  var delta = diff(requestData, template);

  // Search the delta for a deleted property. If found, invalidate the request.
  // If there is any key whose value looks like this:
  // 'email': ['text', 0, 0]
  // it means that the key has been removed and the request is invalid
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I can see in log but how to validate result after compare  ??

Comment: ... this looks like same in question, my problem is can't find the way determine there is key different or value different in javascript.  your commented part `// Search the delta for a deleted property. If found, invalidate the request.`